# PyOpenGL Lighting Color Format Issue

Tags: python, opengl, freeglut

I am attempting to make a 3D rotating torus with lighting. The rotating torus works fine. The lighting is the problem; if I leave `GL_SPECULAR` to its default, the light works fine. When I try to set it to a RGBA float quadruplet (what it is supposed to be) it says it is the incorrect format. I tried to print the actual default value of `GL_SPECULAR` using `print(str(int(GL_SPECULAR)))` it returns the float 4611.0, and I can not find any information on this type of color format. Here is my code:

```
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *

glutInit()

GL_SPECULAR=(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0)

def display():
    glClearColor(1,1,1,1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT1)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glLight(GL_LIGHT1,GL_SPECULAR,GL_POSITION)
    glutSolidTorus(0.3,0.5,10,10)
    glRotatef(1,1,1,0)
    glutSwapBuffers()
    glutPostRedisplay()

def main():
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA)
    glutCreateWindow('window')
    glutDisplayFunc(display)
    glutMainLoop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trian\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 130, in safeCall
    return function( *args, **named )
  File "c:\Users\trian\python\glut.py", line 15, in display
    glLight(GL_LIGHT1,GL_SPECULAR,GL_POSITION)
  File "src\latebind.pyx", line 39, in OpenGL_accelerate.latebind.LateBind.__call__
  File "src\wrapper.pyx", line 314, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
  File "src\wrapper.pyx", line 311, in OpenGL_accelerate.wrapper.Wrapper.__call__
  File "C:\Users\trian\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 415, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
ctypes.ArgumentError: ("argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type", (GL_LIGHT1, (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), c_float(4611.0)))
GLUT Display callback <function display at 0x000001EBCB08E820> with (),{} failed: returning None ("argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type", (GL_LIGHT1, (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), c_float(4611.0)))
PS C:\Users\trian\python>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When lighting ([`GL_LIGHTING`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml)) is enabled, then the color which is associated, is taken from the material parameters  ([`glMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMaterial.xml)).

If you still want to use the current color attribute (which is set by [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml)), then you have to enable [`GL_COLOR_MATERIAL`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml)
and to set the color material paramters ([`glColorMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColorMaterial.xml)):

```py
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)
```

See also [Basic OpenGL Lighting](https://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/opengl_lighting.html).

The instruction `glLight(GL_LIGHT1,GL_SPECULAR,GL_POSITION)` doesn't make any sense at all. Read [`glLight`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es1.1/xhtml/glLight.xml). e.g.:

```py
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, [0, 100, 0, 0])
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, [1, 0, 0, 1]) # red
```